# Checking for existing object javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code that I have saves the html content of the clicked divs in localStorage, while clicking the 'Saved Events' button appends it to the #result div. My challenge is to check and see if objects already exist in #result first before appending, otherwise every time a user clicks the button it will add everything to the div again.

here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selctor").click(function () {
        var i=$(this).attr("rel");
        console.log(i);
        var eventsArray=document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");
        eventSelctd=(eventsArray[i]).outerHTML;

        if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
             localStorage.setItem("schedule "+ i, eventSelctd);
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
        }
    });

    $("#buttn1").click(function () {
    var storaged = Object.keys(localStorage);
    var storageLength = storaged.length;

    for (var i=0; i<storageLength; i++ )
      {
      var key = localStorage.key(i);
      var value = localStorage[key];                

       $("#result").each( function() { 
       var resultRel = $("#result.eventer").attr(rel);
          if ((resultRel) != value) {
          $("#result").append(value);
          }
       });
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please shorten your code to the specific area of problem, instead of post all the HTML and CSS along with it?

Comment: Please learn how to create a **minimal** test case that replicates your issue. Including an entire block of code will not help...

Comment: Hi @roob, created a JSFiddle for your code: http://jsfiddle.net/adamback42/v8q3ex9g/ People really like this type of resource given to them so they can test and play with solutions.

Comment: sorry I meant to create a fiddle n forgot, thank you Adam. Please look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8q3ex9g/13/  i was able to fix the syntax error, now its just the logic that does not seem to work. All help is appreciated

Comment: Working on it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that fiddle supports the use of local storage, so I've got an index.html locally.

Comment: @Adam jsfiddle does support localstorage, the snipit feature here at SO doesnt though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got what you're asking for.

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamback42/jjnq10e5/1/).

- When the user clicks on an event that is already in local storage, I do not allow them to add it again, disallowing for multiples in local storage. If local storage has been cleared, this will not check against multiples.
- When adding saved events to the #results div, I check if the event is already there. I did this by making the keys the rel attribute rather than 'storage '.
- Please see my code comments and feel free to ask any clarification you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.eventer { 
background-color:#9CB2B7; 
padding: 15px; width: 150px; 
height: auto; margin:0; color: #fff; 
letter-spacing:0.7px;
}
.selctor {
background-color: #A0AABA;
width: 180px;
}
a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: 0.7px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
}
#result{
outline: dotted 2px red;
padding-bottom: 150px;
width: 50%;
}
#buttn1 {
float: left;
}
#buttn2 {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="eventer" rel="0"><strong>Event 1 Saturday</strong><br />
yakedi yak</div>
<p class="selctor" rel="0"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
</div>

<div>
<div class="eventer" rel="1"><strong>Event 2 Saturday</strong><br />
more yakedi yak</div>
<p class="selctor" rel="1"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
 </div>

<div>
<div class="eventer" rel="2"><strong>Event 3 Sunday</strong><br />
new yakedi yak</div>
<p class="selctor" rel="2"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
</div>

<div>
<div class="eventer" rel="3"><strong>Event 4 Sunday</strong>
blah blah dooodah</div>
<p class="selctor" rel="3"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
</div>

<input type="submit" id="buttn1" value="Saved Events"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" id="buttn2" value="Remove Events"><br /><br />

<div>Selected Events are:<br />
<div id="result"></div>      
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    // get events
    var events = document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");

    var checkChildrenForMultiples = function(target, elements) {
        // if results has elements, look for events to already be added
        if(elements) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if( $(elements[i]).attr('rel').toString() === target) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }

        // event is NOT already in the result div
        return false;
    }

    // Click selector button
    $(".selctor").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // save the rel attribute as the key
        var key = $(this).attr("rel");

        // save the html for the event selected based on rel
        var eventSelctd = (events[key]).outerHTML;

        // check if localStorage exists for browser and if the event HAS NOT yet been saved
        if(Storage !== undefined && localStorage[key] === undefined) {
            // save key is rel attribute, value is html
            localStorage.setItem(key, eventSelctd);
        } else if (localStorage.key) {
            console.log('Event already saved.');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
        }
    });

    // click on button to show saved events
    $("#buttn1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // save local storage keys as array
        var storedEvents = Object.keys(localStorage);
        var storageLength = storedEvents.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < storageLength; i++) {
            var key = storedEvents[i];
            var value = localStorage[key];

            // if event is not in results div
            if( checkChildrenForMultiples(key, $('#result').children()) === false) {
                // add the event to the div
                $('#result').append(value);
            }
        }

        localStorage.clear();
    });

    // clear local storage
    $("#buttn2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.clear();
        $("#result").html('');
        console.log("Storage is cleared");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To test, copy and paste this code into a text editor and save as index.html. Open that file in the browser and play around. Open the console if you want more info.

Comment: This works too, note that you can create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b0vhxuhy/  Though I would prevent ever saving the duplicate event in the first place rather than prevent adding it later but thats just personal preference

Comment: Thanks @DelightedD0D! Your comment on the main question prompted me to go back and figure out why my ls wasn't working. It's a security setting issue on Chrome. Went into Firefox and it worked just fine for me to create the fiddle. Thanks for the constructive feedback, leading me to question myself and learn something. :-)

Comment: hi Adam, yes this works, thank you so much. I do need to let you know by default localStorage does not add duplicate objects to itself, even tho that part of your effort is appreciated it was not necessary. Thanks again

Comment: just thought i'd mention I access localStorage in Chrome via the Resources tab in Developer Tools - same thing that opens Console. on my end i could access it on the fiddles. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

See here.

```
$("#result").each( function() { 
    var resultRel = $("#result.eventer").attr(rel);
    if ((resultRel) != value) {
        $("#result").append(value);
    }
});
```

1. `#result.eventer` means the element which has id `result` and which **also** has class name `eventer`. I think you thought `#result .eventer`, means the element `.eventer` in `#result`.
2. `$("#result").each` is useless. `.each` throws `#result` instead of children of it.
3. `$("#result .eventer").attr("rel")` is **first** `#result .eventer` element's `rel` attribute. Variable `rel` seems like doesn't defined yet.

So here's my code.

```
$("#buttn1").click(function () {
var storaged = Object.keys(localStorage);
var storageLength = storaged.length;
var resultEventer = $("#result .eventer");

    for (var i=0; i<storageLength; i++)
    {
        var el = $(localStorage[storaged[i]]); // localStorage.key(i) == storaged[i]
        if (resultEventer.filter("[rel='" + el.attr("rel") + "']").length == 0) {
            $("#result").append(el);
        }
    }
});
```

`.filter("[rel='rel value']")` means find the element which attribute `rel` is 'rel value'. and I wrapped your `value` by `$` because I need `value`'s `rel` attribute.

Is the `rel` unique attribute?

Comment: hi Xnuk, this works too thank you, and shorter code too. Really appreciate pointing out 2 and 3, that explains why I kept getting 'error rel undefined'. Yes rel is a unique attribute. I am working on a two-day calendar of events and i thought rel might be a unique enough attribute for each item. If you think that is not a good idea then by all means let me know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8q3ex9g/24/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".selctor").click(function () {
        //get index of clicked div 
        var i = $('.selctor').index($(this)); 

        //use that to get the outerHTML of the matching eventer div
        //this needs `jQuery.fn.outerHTML` down at the bottom to work
        var eventSelctd = $('.eventer:eq('+ i +')' ).outerHTML(); 

        if (typeof(Storage) != 'undefined') {
            //check if we aready have some events saved
            if(localStorage.getItem('myEvents')){
                //if so get them as an array
               var myEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage['myEvents']);

                //make sure the current `eventSelctd` is not already in our array
               if($.inArray(eventSelctd, myEvents ) == -1){
                   //if not add it to the array then update `localStorage["myEvents"] `
                   myEvents.push( eventSelctd  );
                   localStorage["myEvents"] = JSON.stringify( myEvents );
               }
               else{
                   //warn that this event is already selected
                    alert('event is already in storage');
               }

            }
            else{
                //if no `myEvents` exists in localStorage, create it as an array holding just the current `eventSelctd`
                localStorage["myEvents"] = JSON.stringify( [ eventSelctd  ] )
            }
        }
        else {
             document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
        }
    });

    $("#buttn1").click(function () {
        //get the stored events
        var myRetrievedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage['myEvents']);
        $("#result").html(''); //added this to clear the div before adding events
        //loop through the events appending each to the results div
        $(myRetrievedEvents).each(function(index, element){

            $("#result").append(element);

        });

    });

    $("#buttn2").click(function(){
        localStorage.clear();
    $("#result").html('');
       console.log("Storage is cleared");
    });
});

jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
```

Comment: this does not work, sorry, every time you click on 'Saved Events' it adds the data from localStorage again to the end of the div.

Comment: @roob I added `$("#result").html(''); ` before the loop to clear the div before adding in the events, fixed now